# Multiple developers on a single Mac Pro

Tags: ios, xcode, appcode

My development team of 5 people is about to start working on an already existing native iOS app.
At the time being, we are all using Linux/Windows machines and we're going to have access to one Mac Pro which is one of those cylindrical machines with 6 cores and 32GBs of RAM.
The requirement for us is to develop using Xcode or AppCode.

Is there a way for us to work remotely on that Mac without having to buy a Mac for every developer? Can we login on that machine with more than one user and run multiple instances of Xcode and iOS emulators at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, remote access is still more or less the same as physical access and having 5 people work on it at the same time will be messy.

Even if you managed to get 5 instances of Xcode running somehow, that machine would struggle, even a single instance can use up a lot of the machine's resources.